# All categories for each week and group

Tags: sql, join

Hi I have a data source as such

Data:

| Weeknum | Group | Priority | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202106 | A | High | 10 |
| 202106 | B | Medium | 15 |
| 202107 | A | Medium | 88 |

Priorities:

| Priority |
| --- |
| High |
| Medium |
| Low |

The data has already been grouped such that each weeknum+group+priority is unique. What I need to do is return the full list of priorities for each week/group including zeros:

| Weeknum | Group | Priority | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202106 | A | High | 10 |
| 202106 | A | Medium | 0 |
| 202106 | A | Low | 0 |
| 202106 | B | High | 0 |
| 202106 | B | Medium | 15 |
| 202106 | B | Low | 0 |
| 202107 | A | High | 0 |
| 202107 | A | Medium | 88 |
| 202107 | A | Low | 0 |

It doesn't matter if it also returns records for 202107/B as well but it *must* return a record for each priority.

Any help appreciated. :\

Comment: Please include the DB Engine and version you are using

Comment: Need a dataset of all possible combinations of weeknum/group/priority. How this is accomplished depends on the database you work with. In Access this can be done with a query including both tables and has no JOIN - this results in Cartesian association of records and every combination is built. Then join that dataset to the aggregate calc query with compound join on the 3 fields using LEFT or RIGHT join (I forget which).

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. Can you specify from which tables you want this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and then `left join` to bring in the columns you want:

```
select wg.weeknum, wg.group, p.priority,
       coalesce(t.total, 0) as total
from (select distinct weeknum, group
      from t
     ) wg cross join
     priorities p left join
     t
     on t.weeknum = wg.weeknum and t.group = wg.group and
        t.priority = p.priority;
```

Comment: Thats it. Perfect.